# Please help proving a sequence is less than a number using induction

Tags: sequences-and-series, induction

I need to prove that $$a_n=\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n <3$$ using induction. Any help would be great!

Comment: You need to give the definition for $a_n$

Comment: I just added the an to show that it is a sequence. I should have just left it as (1+1/n)^n<3

Comment: You don't need induction. Binomial theorem will work here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n&=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^k}\\\\
&=2+\sum_{k=2}^n\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^k}\\\\
&\le 2+\sum_{k=2}^n\frac{1}{k!}\\\\
&\le 2+\sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac{1}{2^{k-1}}\\\\
&=2+\frac{1/2}{1/2}\\\\&=3
\end{align}$$

---

Here, we show that $\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^k}\le \frac1{k!}$ for $k\ge 2$.  Note that upon expanding $\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^k}$, we obtain

$$\begin{align}
\binom{n}{k}\frac{1}{n^k}&=\frac{n!}{k!\,(n-k)!}\frac{1}{n^k}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{k!}\frac{n!}{(n-k)!\,n^k}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{k!}\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)(n-3)\cdots (n-k+3)(n-k+2)(n-k+1)}{n^k}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{k!}\left(1-\frac1n\right)\left(1-\frac2n\right)\left(1-\frac3n\right)\cdots \left(1-\frac{k-3}n\right)\left(1-\frac{k-2}n\right)\left(1-\frac{k-1}n\right)\\\\
&\le \frac1{k!}
\end{align}$$

Comment: I'm not sure how 1/k factorial is greater than n choose k * 1/n^k

Comment: @adevina I've added an explanation at the end of the answer.